# Inherited class is not part of Entity Framework model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, knockout.js

**Situation**:

I have an ASP.NET MVC webapp with a SQL Server back-end that is managed using Entity Framework.

I have a c# class that Entity Framework uses to update entities in the database (duh). However, for the user to actually update that model, I throw that on an admin page that uses Knockout.

When Knockout handles deletes, it adds a `_destroy` property to the Javascript object, and it make a AJAX call to an `Update` method in a specific ASP.NET MVC controller. To retrieve this `_destroy` property, I have a second C# class that simply inherits the first and adds `_destroy` as a nullable bool property.

**Problem**:

As I try to pass this inhered object back to Entity Framework to update (or delete) the entity, it throws an exception:

> The entity type Foo is not part of the model for the current context

Entity Framework doesn't know about this inherited class (and it shouldn't, it only makes sense within the web-app), but it will not *just use the base class' properties to perform the update*.

**Question**:

Do I need to redesign how I pass this inherited object to EF? Is it possible to save this updated entity?

Is there another option, other than just *copying* my base class with the added `_destroy` nullable bool and casting it? (code smell)

**Example**:

bar.cs

```
 public class Bar
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
 }
```

foo.cs

```
 public class Foo : Bar
 {
     public bool? _destroy { get; set; }
 }
```

MyController.cs

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Update(CancellationToken token, params Foo[] foos)
{
    var deletefoos = foos.Where(x => x._destroy.HasValue && x._destroy.Value).Select((Bar b) => b).ToArray();
    await _myEntityFrameworkAbstraction.DeleteAllTheseFoosAsync(token, deletefoos);

    //similar update call
}
```

myentityframeworkabstraction.cs

```
...
_context.Entry(updatebars).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatebars);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(token);
...
_context.Set<Bar>().RemoveRange(deletebars);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(token);
...
```

Comment: Personally I would keep your entities away from the web app completely and use view models instead.

Comment: How about using containment instead of inheritance.

Comment: what's the issue with using the code you have or `foos.Where().Cast<Bar>()`?

Comment: @IvanStoev That could work, I'll give it a go... don't know why I didn't think of that before. `public Bar BarEntity { get ; set; }` it looks so easy it hurts.

Comment: DavidG's suggestion will hurt less but it will fare much better when you have bigger and more complex models.